# QThread: Call a signal in the right thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread, qtimer

I have some very time consuming tasks to execute in a GUI application, and I want them to be threaded so it won't freeze my GUI..

To do so, I created a thread, and started a timer. I connected the timeout() method from my timer to the time-consuming function I want to paralellize, in the "run" method of my thread, but when the signal is called, the time-consuming function is called in the main thread instead of the one I created.

Here's my code, simplified for the example:

```
void MyThread::run()
{
   m_pTimer = new QTimer()
   connect(m_pTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(timeConsumingMethod()));
   m_pTimer->start(x);
}
```

I printed the value of the static method QThread::currentThread() in "timeConsumingMethod", in MyThread::run() and in my main, and its value is the same as the one in my main.

How can I make my function run in the separated thread? And more important why is my code wrong?

Comment: Even though asker noted the question is answered in the duplicate (so close away), it's not exacty same. The described issue is, because connection uses `Qt::Autoconnection`, and the QThread `this` has thread affinity with the main thread (it *never* has thread affinity with the thread it controls), so signal is queued and slot called by main thread's event loop. So solution is indeed to move `timeConsumingMethod()` to another `QObject`, and create an instance with same thread affinity as the timer.

Answer (score 0):

"You’re doing it wrong." :)

try this:

myworker.h

```
#include ...

class MyWorker : public QObject {
   Q_OBJECT
public:
   explicit MyWorker(QObject* parent = 0);
public slots:
   void timeConsumingMethod();
}
```

myworker.cpp

```
#include "myworker.h"

#include ...

MyWorker::MyWorker(QObject* parent) : 
   QObject(parent) 
{
   /*
   ...
   */
}

void MyWorker::timeConsumingMethod() {
   /*
   ...
   */
}
```

code

```
/*...*/
MyWorker* worker = new MyWorker();
QThread* workerThread = new QThread();
QTimer* timer = new QTimer();


worker->moveToThread(workerThread);
worker->connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), SLOT(timeConsumingMethod()));

// don't forget proper obj deletion
// not the best way, but...
worker->connect(workerThread, SIGNAL(destroyed()), SLOT(deleteLater());

workerThread->start();
timer->start(x);
```

in that case worker will "live" in workerThread. QT SIGNAL-SLOT mechanism supports connection between objects in different threads.

that approach much better than "procedural way" by reimplementing run() method and QThread inheritance

worker works, QThread controls thread

source: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Threads_Events_QObjects